# AWS MSK Authenticate with bearer tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, openid-connect, bearer-token, aws-msk

Since AWS MSK supports Kafka versions up to `3.3.1`, are there any resources which show how to configure a cluster to authenticate Producers & Consumers with Bearer Tokens, as per [KIP-768](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=186877575)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though MSK supports Apache Kafka versions up to 3.3.1, at this moment MSK doesn't expose listeners for `sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER`.

Available mechanisms for SASL_SSL protocol implementation are:

- `AWS_MSK_IAM` - with [IAM integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html) (listeners are on a port 9098)
- `SCRAM-SHA-512` - with [AWS Secrets Manager integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html) (listeners are on a port 9096)

In addition, MSK supports mTLS implementation for SSL protocol with [AWS Certificate Manager integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-authentication.html) (listeners are on a port 9094)

Comment: Are you aware of any news regarding this feature on the AWS side? Any roadmaps or estimated time for this feature to be added to MSK?

Comment: I'd recommend to contact account or support teams, or you could inquire about it by using feedback option on [Authentication doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/kafka_apis_iam.html)